# Method File.Move (path) takes too long

Tags: excel, vba

I have this part code in excell

```
  If FSO.fileExists(OldName) Then ' FSO is fileSystemObject
      Cells(1, 3).Value = "Passed"
      Set source = FSO.getfile(OldName)
      source.Move (NewName)
  end if
```

where `OldName` is somthing like "C:\doc\file.txt" 
and `NewName` is something like "C:\doc\NewName\file.txt"

Directory C:\doc\NewName contains ~20 000 txt files and line `source.Move (NewName)` takes about 4min to execute (file size 2kB, computer is really old...)
If i use empty dir, code runs in a second.

I am not allowed to use another dir, and i can't delete any files from it.

Can anyone explain why it takes so long, and what is the options to reduce the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i still have no clue why it takes so long, but i found a workaround.

I use this approach to copy files

```
Shell "cmd.exe /S /C move " & oldName & " " & newName, windowStyle:=vbHide
```

this runs invisible command console that moves the file.
VBA does not wait command line to finish and continues with other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
If FSO.fileExists(OldName) Then ' FSO is fileSystemObject
  Cells(1, 3).Value = "Passed"
  Set source = FSO.getfile(OldName)
  Name OldName As NewName
```

end if

**UPDATE**

ok then you can try this:

```
If Len(Dir(OldName)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "File does not exist"
Else
    Name OldName As NewName
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the execution time is still the same

Comment: cant see how this can solve a problem - i already tried to use ` Name OldName As NewName` and it takes the same time

Comment: the if statement changed, it now uses Dir to check if the file exists, because i think the problem comes from checking the file rather then moving it

Comment: I am quite sure that it;s because `source.Move (NewName)`
Code runs smoothly if i disable this line